# Confirm redirect in Cypress with out actually redirecting

Tags: testing, cross-domain, cypress

I have a page that I'm testing and it has a button to press to get additional information. Normally when clicked it would navigate you to a different site (different domain). Now I know the limitations of Cypress and cross domain access in tests. However, it would suffice for my test to confirm that the `location` had been set to the new address with out having to verify anything on the target page.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is it possible to get the URL of the different site, that you can use cy.request()? Then you could check the response.

Comment: I don't even need the response. Our responsibility is just to redirect to a specific url. We don't control target's content so that could be problematic anyway. This would be easy enough if it was driven by a link, but I need to confirm the code is creating the correct redirect.

Comment: Does the button has `href` attribute?